# $\log$-classes of irrationals

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, approximation-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers. For $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we let the *(upper) density* of $A$ be defined by $d^+(A) = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty} \frac {|A\cap \{0,\ldots, n\}|}{n+1}$.

Moreover, we define the "logarithm" of $A$ by $$\log(A) = \big\{\max\{0,\lfloor\log_2(a+1)\rfloor\}: a\in A \big\}.$$
Inductively, we set $\log^{(0)}(A) = A$ and $\log^{(n+1)}(A) = \log(\log^{(n)}(A))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For any $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, let  $$\alpha_r(n)=\min\{|r-\frac{m}{n}|: m\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ be the best approximation of $r$ that can be obtained using $n$ as the denominator.

We inductively define $\text{appr}_r:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, the *approximation sequence* of $r$:

- $\text{appr}_r(0) = 1$, and
- $\text{appr}_r(n+1) = \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}: m \geq \text{appr}_r(n) \text{ and } \alpha_r(m) < \alpha_r(\text{appr}_r(n))\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\text{Approx(r)} = \{\text{appr}_r(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. The *$\log$-class* of $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is set to $n$ if $n$ is the smallest integer such that $$d^+(\log^{(n)}(\text{Approx}(r)) > 0,$$ and we say the $\log$-class of $r$ is $\infty$ if $d^+(\log^{(k)}(\text{Approx}(r)) = 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Questions.** For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is there $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with $\log$-class $n$? And is there $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with $\log$-class $\infty$?

Comment: Choose your favorite integer-valued function $f$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log^n f(n)=\infty$. Then $\sum 1/2^{f(n)}$ will have infinite $\log$-class.

Comment: The reason why `\text{appr}` rather than `\operatorname{appr}` is incorrect LaTeX or MathJax usage can be seen in the behavior of things like `\cos`, `\det`, `\log`, `\max`, etc. In $\cos x$, coded as `\cos x`, you see more space to the right of $\cos$ than you see in $\cos(x),$ coded as `\cos(x)`, and $2\cos(x),$ coded as `2\cos(x)` does not look the same as $2\text{cos}(x),$ coded as `2\text{cos}(x)`. The thing that makes one font look far better to you than another is a large number of little details like this that most people don't notice. Donald Knuth had that in$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$mind when he invented TeX. And he said so. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy for the TeX hints!